# Closing an object inside the objects using statement

Tags: c#, object, using

I'm trying to find out if I can close a stream like this inside a using statement and open another?

Here is the code:

```
string combined = Path.Combine(path, some + ".txt");
if (File.Exists(combined))
{
    using (TextReader obj2 = new StreamReader(combined))
    {
        string line = obj2.ReadLine();
        if (line != null && !line.Contains("Mon"))
        {   
            obj2.Close();
            TextWriter obj = File.AppendText(combined);
            obj.WriteLine("Mon\t\t\t|Thue\t\t\t|Wedn\t\t\t|Thurs\t\t\t|Friday\t\t\t|Sat\t\t\t|Sun\t\t\t    ");
            obj.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it in visual studio , see what happens

Comment: that's great advice. just.. try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless if it's possible and what happens, **just don't do it**. Why? Because:

1. it's ugly,
2. it's against the purpose of the `using` statement,
3. it's barely readable code,
4. it's poorly maintainable,
5. it's not undestandable by anyone else, and not even by yourself starting from tomorrow,
6. it's an *apparent code smell* — an indication you hardly know what you are doing and that you are struggling with structuring your code properly.

---

Update: The direct consequence of points (3) and (5) above is that I misunderstood your code and thought you were assigning the new instance of `TextReader` into `obj2`. I just didn't spot there was some other variable `obj` with a barely different name.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is correct. You cannot, however, "reuse" `obj2`; that variable is readonly inside the `using` block. Closing and reopening the same file using a different object reference is safe; the `using` keyword simply guarantees that `Dispose()` will get called at the end of the block. On a `StreamReader`, `Dispose()` simply closes the stream, but since you've already done that inside the block, nothing will happen.

Also note that in your example, `obj` is not protected by `using`: you are *not* guaranteed that `obj.Dispose()` will be called before the block exits. This is okay, though, since you're explicitly closing the stream yourself.